# Why didn't the Jedi pursue Maul more vigorously?

Tags: star-wars, darth-maul

After events in Episode 1, Jedi (and mostly everyone else) assumed Darth Maul to be dead. Yet, he reappears and challenges Obi-Wan who gets beaten pretty badly.

Considering the importance of Maul (he was after all One of Two, he definitely knew  Darth Sidious' identity, and presumably other Sith secrets), and his combat capability, why didn't the Jedi send some more experienced and powerful masters or knights after him (Yoda, Windu, Anakin, Fisto, or even better, all of them). Instead, they leisurely let him rampage, with Kenobi as only Jedi confronting him (although Kenobi considers himself and Ventress as outmatched against Maul and Savage Opress). The only so called help Obi-Wan gets from other Jedi is weak Jedi Master Adi Gallia - she gets killed relatively easy  by Savage Opress and Savage is shown to be no match for Maul.

Later Palpatine himself gets down to business, cutting lose ends, but it seems completely counter-intuitive even for arrogant and not-so-smart Jedi to just let this opportunity slip away. I'm pretty certain Yoda and Windu could disarm Maul and capture him alive. After that... it is quite possible Maul would blurt something out, considering his rage and lack of control. Even Opress could be valuable as prisoner, and events could force Palpatine to prematurely reveal his hand.

Answer (score 6):

For a while, it was unknown whether or not Maul and Savage survived their shuttle crash in "Revival." Palpatine suppressed attempts to confirm their deaths by arguing it would waste Republic resources. Yoda agreed, promising that the Jedi will go after Maul if he reveals himself again.

> **Palpatine:** I think we have closure on this matter, master Kenobi.
>
> **Kenobi:** I disagree, Chancellor. Everything we've learned from this is that the Sith are persistent. They will not die.
>
> **Palpatine:** I understand your reservations, Master Kenobi, but I am afraid we can no longer allow this personal matter of yours to be a Republic concern. It does not appear this Darth Maul is a direct threat to the Republic. We need to redirect your efforts to the cause at hand: Stopping Count Dooku and thus ending the Clone Wars.
>
> **Kenobi:** Maul was trying to build an army of pirates.
>
> **Palpatine:** So let him. Let him play with the rabble. They're just petty crooks. It is of no relevance to the Senate compared to the Separatist threat.
>
> ...
>
> **Yoda:** A personal matter this is for you. Clouded your judgment may be. In time, if he lives, reveal himself again Maul will. And then swiftly we shall act.

In "The Lawless," the Jedi were unaware of his presence on Mandalore and were unable to help with the situation due to Mandalore's neutrality.

> **Mundi:** Without involvement from the Separatists, this is an internal affair for the Mandalorians. I'm afraid we cannot help.

Comment: Whole point of question is why did Yoda and other, presumably "wise" Jedi Masters agreed with this. Maul was vastly more important then Separatists, because he knew much more about Sidious then any other person except Count Dooku. Jedi were aware that Sith somehow orchestrated whole war, so certainly this was not just a personal matter for Kenobi.

Comment: @rs.29 In the canon comic, Sons of Dathomir, the Jedi theorized that Dooku was the Sith Master and Maul was the apprentice. This comic takes place after the Lawless episode. The Jedi confronted Maul and Dooku, but both managed to escape. After that, the Jedi learned about the existence of Sidious and there wasn't enough time to handle Maul. There was also supposed to be a Clone Wars episode where Ahsoka engages Maul, but that episode was never created.